# Plan to upgrade version of Dropwizard in GraphDB?

Tags: upgrade, dropwizard, graphdb

We are maintaining an application using GraphDB as a backend service. This application is built on spring-boot, and we are testing the application with a test-dependency to graphdb-runtime. It seems like GDB relies on an old version of Dropwizard (3.x), which had it's last release many years ago. Version [3.2.6](https://github.com/dropwizard/metrics/releases/tag/v3.2.6) seems to be the last 3.x version.

This old version dependency clashes with the spring-boot dependency management (4.x), and these Dropwizard dependencies are managed manually. This is something we would like to avoid. Are there any plans to lift the Dropwizard dependency in GDB to version 4.x?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately upgrading the version of dropwizard isn’t straightforward because of major differences between dropwizard 3.x and 4.x but we’ll see if we can plan this for a future GraphDB version.